# Cordova jarsigner and create new file

Tags: cordova, build, apk, release, jarsigner

I use cordova 3.4.1, how can i sign a unsigned apk file and create a new file likes: AppName-release-signed.apk in /bin? Because i don't want to re-compile my app every times. Now, it seems that i signed directly onto my AppName-release-unsigned.apk.

Here it's my command line now:

```
 jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore /path/to/AppName-release-unsigned.apk alias_name

 zipalign -v 4 /path/to/AppName-release-unsigned.apk AppName.apk
```

And what i need:

```
 zipalign -v 4 /path/to/AppName-release-signed.apk AppName.apk
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added the option and it works

```
-signedjar AppName.apk
```

So:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore /path/to/AppName-release-unsigned.apk -signedjar AppName.apk alias_name
```

That command give us a signed file named "AppName.apk" and then:

```
zipalign -v 4 AppName.apk AppName-final.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

When you launch

`jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore /path/to/AppName-release-unsigned.apk alias_name`

The file AppName-release-unsigned.apk gets signed (the file is modified).

Then with

`zipalign -v 4 /path/to/AppName-release-unsigned.apk AppName.apk`

zipalign generates the file AppName.apk in your current folder, this file being an aligned version of the file AppName-release-unsigned.apk.

So for your purpose, all you need is

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore /path/to/AppName-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
zipalign -v 4 /path/to/AppName-release-unsigned.apk /path/to/AppName-release-signed.apk
```

Don't you?

Comment: Sorry, it's not what i want. I found it, we can add "-signedjar AppName.apk" into the options of jarsigner and then, it would create a new signed file. After that, we can launch "zipalign". Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Maybe add your own answer and accept it, like this people looking for the option will have higher chances to find it.